# probability, normal distribution help?

Tags: probability

Betsy is testing whether school is more enjoyable when students are making high grades. She asked 150 students if they enjoyed school and whether their GPA was above or below 3.5. She found that 35 of the 60 students with a GPA above 3.5 reported that they enjoyed school, and 15 of the 90 students with a GPA below 3.5 reported that they enjoyed school. What is the probability that a student with a GPA below 3.5 does not enjoy school?

Is the answer 50%?
90-15=75
75 divided by 150= .5 
50%?

Comment: Just to check. You randomly select a student of the 150. The question then asks: Given that the student has a GPA below 3.5, what is the probability that they do not enjoy school? Or, by chance is the question: Given that the student does not enjoy school, what is the probability that their GAP is below 3.5? These are both common questions with this type of problem and will lead to different answers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $\frac{75}{90} = \frac{5}{6}$,  since the probability is conditional on the student having a GPA below 3.5... That is, the question could be restated as "From all the students with GPA below 3.5 (90), what is the fraction of them that does not enjoy school?"